# How to increment skip count until results is found in API?

Tags: javascript, api

I have the following api which returns thousands of result: http://xxx/xxx/CarRoutes. The API creator however limits only 50 results to be return at once. Hence, to see get another 50 more results to be returned, "?$skip=50" needs to be used. Also, the api url does not allow to add in  any parameters behind.

Now I would like to search for CarRoutes id = 123. How can I auto increment the $skip count until results is found?

Appreciate if it can be done Javascript language.

Current idea I have, which is not efficient.

```
function getInfo() {


        $.ajax({
            url: "http://xxx/xxx/CarRoutes?$skip="+skip,
            success: function(result) {
               
                var obj = JSON.stringify(result);
                var routetimeobj = JSON.parse(obj);
                var data = routetimeobj['value'];

                var data_filter = data.filter(element => element.CarRoute =="123");

                if(data_filter.length==0){
                  skip+=50;
                 getInfo();
                return;
                }
          });
           

      };
```

Comment: Would need to post what you have tried so far and where you are stuck ? The question right now seems too generic to be answered.

Comment: SO is not a free coding service. Please update your question with the code that your stuck on. We can then help you understand and solve the problem. See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @NisanthReddy, I have edited the qn to include my idea, which is not efficient yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to follow the pattern you are using in your code, you can add a parameter to your function

`function getInfo(skip)`

and when you are calling again, call it like this

`getInfo(skip + 50);`